# Simple calculation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert the total amount calculated but I don't know why instead of calculating its just appending the values.

**The code:**

```
    $('#main button').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    parts = id.split('_');
    item_id = parts[0];
    pairs = $('#'+item_id+'_pairs').val();
    females = $('#'+item_id + '_females').val();
    males = $('#'+item_id + '_males').val();
    if(pairs >0){
        counted_pairs = pairs*2;
    }else{
        counted_pairs = 0;
    }
    total_fishes = (males + females + counted_pairs);
    alert(total_fishes);
});
```

If I add 1 pair 1 male and 1 female in form it should show 4 total but its showing 111 seems appending not calculating?

Comment: `val` returns a string. You need to somehow cast the values to numbers.

Comment: Ways to convert a string to a number include `Number(string)`, `string*1`, `string+0`, `parseInt(string)`, `parseFloat(string)`, `string/1`, and probably other methods.

Comment: Actually `string+0` doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: @Shmiddty: The best being `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, the most direct being a unary `+`.

Comment: But `+string` will work. Used like `pairs = +$('#'+item_id+'_pairs').val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change total_fishes = (males + females + counted_pairs); to this:

```
total_fishes = ((males * 1 + females * 1) * 1 + counted_pairs * 1);
```

This **will** work, I know it seems odd but Javascript converts the variables to numbers when u use * 1 + value * 1. I can't explain why but I saw this peace of code a couple of years ago in cPanel x and I use it a lot.

Edit:

There is actually a difference when you are using user input you can check if the value is wrong using isNaN this will not work when you use parseInt because it supresses the error and tries to create an integer anyways.

TestCode:

```
var males = "2,4";
var females = "3";
var counted_pairs = "33";

var result = ((males * 1 + females * 1) * 1 + counted_pairs * 1);
var resultb = (parseInt(males) + parseInt(females * 1) + parseInt(counted_pairs));

if (isNaN(result)) {
 alert("Input is wrong my method");   
}

if (isNaN(resultb)) {
 alert("Input is wrong using parseint");   
}​
```

Result: Only the first alert screen will be shown.

Comment: There is **zero** reason to throw multiplication into this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's shorthand to convert a string to a number.

Comment: @Vega: It's a *bad* trick to convert to number. `parseInt` or `parseFloat` are better, as they let you control the number base used so you don't get unexpected results. At the *very* least, if you insist on leaving yourself open to those unexpected results, use a unary `+` or `Number(str)` rather than multiplication.

Comment: also this should not be the accepted answer as `parseInt` without radix also gives unexpected errors

Answer (score 5):

you need to do a numeric addition. What you have is a string concatenation.

Try converting it to a number using `parseInt`.

```
total_fishes = (parseInt(males, 10) + parseInt(females, 10) + counted_pairs);
```

**Note:** I haven't applied for counted_pairs as it will be a number because of `counted_pairs = pairs*2;`

Comment: @user1494854: make sure that you use this on production. +1

Answer (score 2):

Parse the values to numbers when you get them:

```
pairs = parseInt($('#'+item_id+'_pairs').val(), 10);
females = parseInt($('#'+item_id + '_females').val(), 10);
males = parseInt($('#'+item_id + '_males').val(), 10);
```

Now, when `pairs` is a number, you don't have to check for the zero specifically, as `0 * 2` will calculate just fine:

```
counted_pairs = pairs * 2;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improe the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the variables you are adding holds a string value, JavaScript will append the values with each other as if all are strings. Make sure all your variables hold integer values; otherwise convert them to integers by parsing as the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your values to integers before your if statement...

```
pairs = parseInt($('#'+item_id+'_pairs').val(), 10);

females = parseInt($('#'+item_id + '_females').val(), 10);

males = parseInt($('#'+item_id + '_males').val(), 10);
```

Comment: I think this is same as what [Guffa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13753962/297641) has answered.

Comment: Yes it is, he posted his answer while I was writing mine. When I submitted mine, the page refreshed and then I saw his.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating strings, not adding values. Use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to add numbers.

```
total_fishes = (parseFloat(males) + parseFloat(females) + parseFloat(counted_pairs));
```